# MTG Life tracker. Show change in number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ecmascript-6

Im making a MTG (Magic The Gathering) life tracker. Just for fun really. Even tho its extremely messy written and such.

it does the job *OK.*

### https://isthaturcard.no/Life-Tracker/

---

[image]

---

#### Goal / Issues I'm having

I want to add an indicator to show how many times someone clicked or adjusted the life total on one of the players.

Meaning;
**If** i were to adjust the life total on one of the players either up or down. a little box fading in displaying how many times that button was just then clicked, before it fades out again. but then *"resets"* that visualization.

So that then also *next* time someone were to adjust the life total, visualize the changes **they** made.

Visualizing the changes up and down.

Using jquery or vanilla JS, is there a fairly simple way to do this?

If not ill probably end up doing something with jquery's [.change](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref) `.change(function(){//"count recent clicks somehow"` or something. and have it slap on a `+` or `-` depending on what button was pressed.

any input and help would mean the world!

---

Comment: Just as a heads up: you should style the icons with `cursor: pointer`. Nice design though 

Comment: @Spectric ur right. i didnt even think about it because im going to be using this on my ipad mostly. but you are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had overcomplicated stuff **A LOT**

Here is an example of it working!

```js
var lastFadeOutTime = 0;
var fadeOutTimeout;

function changeLife(player, amount) {
  var lifeTotalElement = $(`#lifeTotal${player.charAt(player.length-1)}`);
  var historyLogElement = $(`#historyLog${player.charAt(player.length-1)}`);
  var visualizationElement = $('#visualization');

  var currentLife = parseInt(lifeTotalElement.text());
  var newLife = currentLife + amount;

  // Update life total
  lifeTotalElement.text(newLife);

  // Update history log
  var historyItem = amount > 0 ? `+${amount}` : `${amount}`;
  historyLogElement.prepend(`<p>${historyItem}</p>`);

  // Update visualization
  var totalChanges = 0;

  // Only consider changes after the last fade out
  historyLogElement.find('p').slice(0, 1000).each(function() {
    totalChanges += parseInt($(this).text());
  });

  // Update visualization
  visualizationElement.text(`${totalChanges}`);
  visualizationElement.fadeIn();

  // Clear the previous timeout
  clearTimeout(fadeOutTimeout);

  // Hide visualization after 5 seconds and reset the history log
  fadeOutTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (currentTime - lastFadeOutTime >= 3000) {
      visualizationElement.fadeOut(function() {
        historyLogElement.find('p').remove();
        lastFadeOutTime = currentTime;
      });
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px;
}

.player {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.life-total {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.history-log {
  display: none;
  /* hide history log */
}

.visualization {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
  /* initially hide */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Magic: The Gathering Life Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="player" id="player1">
      <h2>Player 1</h2>
      <div class="life-total" id="lifeTotal1">40</div>
      <button class="btn" onclick="changeLife('player1', 1)">+1</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="changeLife('player1', -1)">-1</button>
      <div class="history-log" id="historyLog1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="player" id="player2">
      <h2>Player 2</h2>
      <div class="life-total" id="lifeTotal2">40</div>
      <button class="btn" onclick="changeLife('player2', 1)">+1</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="changeLife('player2', -1)">-1</button>
      <div class="history-log" id="historyLog2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="visualization" id="visualization"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: one question: why is not visualization shown separately? isn't the visualization end result confusing when + and - are done for both players multiple times? Also, shall it done by jQuery too? I can then try and share my answer

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant im not sure i got what you mean. because you would just adjust one players life total at a time. the visualization would fade out, reset itself, and then vizualize again after.